# How can I create a belongs_to model with the relative has_many id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
    @story = Story.create(story_params, listing_id: @listing.id)
```

Story belongs to listing, I'm trying to have it so upon creation the listing id is passed in so the story is attached to that listing. However, I am getting the following error upon trying to use this.

wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)

on line:

```
  @story = Story.create(story_params, listing_id: @listing.id)
```

How should I be doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
@story = @listing.stories.create(story_params)
```